# Enable both IPN and INS Response in 2 checkout

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment, 2checkout

just wanted to know that my current payment system is based on INS response can i turn on INS and IPN both response at one time ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to turn on ipn notification then 2c0 will send both responses automatically